# Storing and editing configuration for Java EE applications

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-6

*UPDATE*: See my blog post on this topic about a year after this was written: http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/07/java-ee-7-needs-improvements-in-app.html

... for references to the Java EE 7 planning discussion on this topic.

---

I've mostly finished writing a small Java EE 6 application, and am in the process of replacing the hard-coded preferences with a proper dynamic configuration interface.

I'm not sure how - or, more specifically, where - to store settings. There **must** be some obvious, "standard" way to do this that's expected to "just work" across various frameworks and containers, but for the life of me I cannot find it.

What I want is a simple way to load and store settings, one that works across different app servers and OSes, doesn't require any confguration by the user, and *actually works properly*. The Java Preferences API would be ideal - but seems broken under Glassfish 3.1.

Options for storing configuration would theoretically include:

1. Using context-parameters from the container environment
2. Storing them using the Java Preferences API
3. Reading/writing a properties file ... somewhere
4. Using JPA to store them in a JavaDB provided by the container
5. Putting it in a properties file that's loaded off the classpath
6. Using system properties to set configuration options, or path to a .properties file

This would seem to be a basic requirement that'd be well catered for in an environment where the container supposedly provides you with all the core services you might need - but all these approaches have issues.

A [bug in glassfish](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16222) renders (1) unworkable, and in any case the Glassfish web admin user interface lacks any way to configure context parameters, so you have to use `asadmin' and some less than lovely command line syntax to do it. Context parameters can only be accessed via the ServletContext - which isn't  accessible in a consistent way between frameworks like JSF2, JAX-RS, and raw servlets - but at least Seam Servlet handles that.

What <s>appears to be another bug in glassfish</s> *was a library version conflict between the deployed app and Glassfish* breaks (2). The preferences backend fails to flush preferences to disk, so the stored preferences data is lost when the application server is restarted. The Java Preferences API also seems to be considered a J2SE/desktop thing, despite its inclusion in the Java EE 6 specs.

(3) might work - but there's no way to know where your app has read/write access on the file system and where it should look. You can't make this configurable, as it becomes a chicken-and-egg problem then. Various platform-specific guesses could be applied, but would break in the presence of a SecurityManager.

(4) would work, but it's nuking a fly. It requires that a JavaDB service be running and forces the user to make sure the JDBC and pool resources in the app server are configured properly. It's big and complicated for a simple job, and entity modelling isn't a lovely fit for preferences storage anyway, as it'll mostly land up being key/value structured.

(5) would work, but requires users to know where to put the config file where it'll be found under various different app servers. It also makes it hard for the app to provide any kind of configuration UI because it can't necessarily find the local path to the config file or open it for writing, especially in the presence of a SecurityManager.

(6) would also work, but forces the user to configure the configuration system before they can configure the application. Needless to say, that doesn't excite me, given how relatively complicated deploying the app and creating the resources already is for users who don't already know Glassfish/EE.

So ... how are you handling configuration and storage of options? Have you found a way that lets you "just do it" without the user having to configure anything to allow your app to store its configuration?

Comment: Stay with glassfish 3.0.1 for now.  3.1 appears to need maturing.

Comment: Thorbjørn: I'm running 3.1 because 3.0 has too many massive bugs to be usable for me. Hearing that 3.1 "needs maturing" makes me very, very unhappy. Why the @#$@ are Oracle considering Java EE 7 when the EE 6 stuff is so half-baked, buggy, and internally inconsistent between different APIs? Can I expect better results if I throw in the towel on Glassfish and move to Tomcat or JBoss AS 6?

Comment: I've found 3.0.1 to work very well for us (but 3.0 was buggy). I have not had a closer look at 3.1 A's i SAw a bug report influencng our use.

Comment: Thorbjørn: I guess it depends on what you use. 3.0.1 has broken handling of no-interface local views that mean they don't work for methods inherited from superclasses (https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=13040), is incompatible with Seam Solder due to a variety of bugs, doesn't work with Jersey 1.5, etc etc. I've had more luck with 3.1. That said, now I can't reproduce the issue that was breaking prefs before (wtf?!) so maybe there's hope for using the Preferences API.

Comment: sorry to hear those problems. Are they still present when fully updated 3.0.1 from with the console?  Please follow up when you know if it is still present or the bugs you've hit has been fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: regarding your blog post, I have created a CLI for Java Preferences API which I use along deployment scripts to automate deployment of text configurations: https://github.com/shakiba/preferd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the preferences API was caused by the inclusion of jaxb and stax implementation jars on in the application's war, pulled in by jersey-json . With these excluded (as they're provided by the app server anyway) the preferences API resumed functioning correctly.

It looks like the prefs API with custom UI for setup appears to be the best way to go.

Comment: Here's a discussion thread from 2001 with the same issues. Wow, Java EE is so fast moving.... http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=9360

Comment: On Windows the Preferences API tries to save to the Registry and fails due to lack of permissions for me.   I've read you can manually create Registry keys and or update permission settings as Admin, but this was a turn off.

Answer (score 1):

Though not the environment you spoke about: http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationAdmin.html